# Count the total number of characters of a text dataset

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dataset in a dataframe format which the first colum contains text and in the second on contais labels. I want to cound the total number of characters of my dataset. I implemented a code for the total number of words, but I can not adopt it to characters. I would be grateful if you could help me.

```
# To see the total number of words 
dt['text'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(' '))).sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dt['text'].str.len().sum()
```

This would give you the total number of characters. You can check the doc for `str` from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) (Vectorized string functions for Series and Index.)

Answer (score 0):

You might use `.str.len()` to get lengths, i.e. total number of characters as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['A','BBB','CCCCC']})
print(df['text'].str.len())
```

output

```
0    1
1    3
2    5
Name: text, dtype: int64
```